# aligning buttons on runtime

Tags: delphi, user-interface, runtime

I have a problem with buttons align on runtime. I want them to align in center of the panel. I have TPanel, which contains buttons that are created runtime. I want them dynamically fill the whole panel area evenly.

Let's say I have three buttons in row - each buttons width 50px. And my panel has width 350px.

1. I divide panel width to number of buttons in row (Trunc(350/3)=116). Got button area width.
2. Now I substract the button area width from button width to get the margins (116-50=66)
3. Divide margins to 2 to get left and right margin (Trunc(66/2)=33)
4. And position my buttons, starting from left margin and so on.

But this doesn't work correctly. What I'm doing wrong? Also my panel has a right anchor. So if I resize my form, the panel resizes, but buttons do not align.

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: can you post the code which you are using

Comment: I already found my mistake in code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just a suggestion, use a TGridPanel. Set up columns and set align client on buttons. It should do the same, although I haven't tested it.